ServiceWorker cant cache filtered value
I have a .NET project, and in this project, I use a service worker for offline functionality. It works correctly on many pages, but on two pages, it doesn't work because the values on these pages are loaded via JavaScript. The service worker can't cache these values. How can I solve this problem?
I tried to cache those JavaScript files with the service worker, but it didn't work.
